# How to add query string parameters to GetFromJsonAsync in a Blazor app?

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'd like to add some query string parameters to the `GetFromJsonAsync` helper method from the 'System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions' library. Reading through the docs and examples, it seems like this helper is more for vanilla API calls that do not provide a lot of intervening for custom headers or parameters, but I don't have clarity on this. It appears to add custom parameters or headers, the preferred method is to use the more raw, `HttpClient.GetAsync` Method.

I suppose I can just string manipulate the `requestUri` parameter of `GetFromJsonAsync` but I'm not seeing this as a mainstream practice. I just want to add some simple query string parameters like the following:

```
'zip': 90210
'units': 'imperial'
```

What is the correct or mainstream way to manipulate the Http call to an API for parameters or headers in a Blazor application?

Comment: I think the mainstream practice would be to use a Post which is designed to pass data.

Comment: No, you should not use a HTTP POST for a GET that requires simply query string parameters, not body parameters. There's also the issue of a POST isn't idempotent, so it causes an issue if incorrectly used for a GET.

Comment: Theoretically agree, but as request data get's more complex, and is in the form of an object, such as for a list request, sending it in gets is more complex.  When get and post were first proposed, I don't think they envisaged today's web.  We really need a Get that accepts a data request in the body.

Comment: Get with query string params is a legit usecase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this works

```
var data = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<MenuApiModel>($"{nameof(Menu)}?menuId=1");
```

Notice I simply put the query param in the url itself.

Comment: Yes I ended up using C# String Interpolation: https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_strings_interpol.php

Comment: @atconway just in case you missed it... I'm also using interpolation in the example.